# Spring Boot: Hibernate не рисует таблицы

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Собираю первый проект на Spring Boot.

Проект собирается и поднимается, но Hibernate не рисует таблицы по сущностям, как должен (то есть, вообще никак). При этом, база подключена (Connection Success).

**build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M7'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.ewerk.gradle.plugins:querydsl-plugin:1.0.9'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl'

group = 'ru.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka')
//  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}

querydsl {
    jpa = true
    querydslSourcesDir = "$buildDir/generated/source/apt/main"
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
# database connection
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=12345

# jpa / hibernate
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Fix Postgres JPA Error:
# Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented.
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

**Точка входа:**

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories("ru.example.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "ru.example.controller",
        "ru.example.service",
        "ru.example.config",
        "ru.example.dto",
        "ru.example.util"})
@EntityScan("ru.example.entity")
@SpringBootApplication
public class HealthMeterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HealthMeterApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Репозиторий:**

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<TestEntity, Long> {
}
```

**Сущности:**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"created"}, ignoreUnknown = true)
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final int START_SEQ = 1000000000;

    private Long id;
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "global_seq", sequenceName = "global_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = START_SEQ)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "global_seq")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "created", updatable = false)
    public LocalDateTime getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    private void setCreated(LocalDateTime created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    @PrePersist
    void onCreate() {
        if (Objects.isNull(this.getCreated())) {
            this.setCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        AbstractEntity that = (AbstractEntity) o;

        if (id != null ? !id.equals(that.id) : that.id != null) return false;
        return created != null ? created.equals(that.created) : that.created == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (created != null ? created.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
```

==========

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class TestEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    private Long name;

    @Column(name = "name")
    public Long getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(Long name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        if (!super.equals(o)) return false;

        TestEntity entity = (TestEntity) o;

        return name != null ? name.equals(entity.name) : entity.name == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Измените свойсто `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`

Comment: да, спасибо, ну, или update. Выделите, пожалуйста, свой ответ в отдельный пост, чтобы я мог его принять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените свойство `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` на:

**update** - Для обновления схемы

**create** - Для создания схемы и удаление предыдущих данных

**create-drop** - Для создания схемы и удаление схемы по окончанию сессии

Подробности можно найти здесь http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional